# Simple use case with Kundera and MysQL

Tags: java, jpa, kundera

I'm new in kundera. My usecase is with Kundera and MySQL. I'm saving an entity using spring's CrudRepository. ID in that entity is AUTO generated.
Kundera is saving that object successfully in DB. but returning wrong ID. and if I'm using that Id to find the data from DB , it returns null.

Could you please let me know if I'm missing any thing.

Entity Class :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "REQUEST_DETAILS")
    public class RequestDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        protected long id;

        @Column(name = "REQUEST_STATUS", nullable = false)
        private String requestStatus;

        // getter setter
    }
```

MAIN class :

```
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring/jpa-config.xml");

            RequestDetailsRepository repository = context.getBean(RequestDetailsRepository.class);

            RequestDetails requestDetails = new RequestDetails();
            requestDetails.setRequestStatus("STARTED");

            RequestDetails updatedRequest = repository.save(requestDetails);
            System.out.println("request id : " + updatedRequest.getId());   // returning wrong ID (probably hashcode of that object)

           // Do some operation

           RequestDetails details = repository.findOne(updatedRequest.getId()); // returning NULL

    }
```

CRUD Repository :

```
    public interface RequestDetailsRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<RequestDetails, Long> {

    }
```

jpa-config.xml :

```
    <beans>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.project" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        </bean>

        <jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.project.repository"/>   

    </beans>
```

Persistence.xml :

```
    <persistence>
        <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
            <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
            <properties>
                <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.rdbms.RDBMSClientFactory" />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                    value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.127.127.215:1433;databaseName=myDB" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
                <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
                <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"
                    value="org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```